# Как остановить MediaPlayer используя слушатель?

Tags: java, android

```
MediaPlayer mp_s; 
mp_s = new MediaPlayer();
    mp_s.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer arg0){
            arg0.start();//Запускаем на воспроизведение
        }
    });
    mp_s.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0){
            Log.i("MyLog","MediaPlayer.onCompletion ");
        }
    });
```

Запускаю на воспроизведение вот так:

```
mp_s.prepareAsync();
```

Но если останавливать вот так:

```
mp_s.Stop();
```

то не отрабатывается

```
onCompletion
```

Как правильно остановить MediaPlayer, чтобы onCompletion отработал окончание вопроизведения?